# kubernetes stack not writable

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I was able to follow all instructions mentioned here and create a cluster.

https://github.com/digitalocean/doks-example

I changed the image to my own, custom image.

```
# /usr/local/bin/kubectl --kubeconfig="k8s-1-14-2-do-0-blr1-1558848628228-kubeconfig.yaml" apply -f manifest1.yaml
service/doks-example1 created
deployment.extensions/doks-example1 created
```

The new app is deployed successfully...

```
# /usr/local/bin/kubectl --kubeconfig="k8s-1-14-2-do-0-blr1-1558848628228-kubeconfig.yaml" get service
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
doks-example    LoadBalancer   10.245.92.169   139.59.48.36    80:31378/TCP     14m
doks-example1   LoadBalancer   10.245.250.95   139.59.49.155   8887:32137/TCP   3m1s
kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.245.0.1      <none>          443/TCP          22m
```

But I am not able to create a new jupyter notebook after logging in. I get a "Forbidden" error.

[image]
How do I make the container writable?

Comment: can you provide your manifest and also logs of your container indicating the error?

Comment: @VasilyAngapov there are few changes made to that yaml file https://github.com/shantanuo/doks-example/commit/b1e4f0f96e27552926e13cf07b2d65893852a0dd

Answer (score 0):

This seems related to cache issue discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2396). Pressing `F5` worked quickly with your configuration